# __init__() got multiple values for argument 'use_technical_indicator' - error

Tags: python, finrl

I can't figure out why I am getting this error. If you can figure it out, I'd appreciate it. If you can provide specific instruction, I'd appreciate it. This code is in one module; there are 7 modules total. [image]
Python 3.7, Mac OS, code from [www.finrl.org](http://www.finrl.org)

```
# Perform Feature Engineering:
df = FeatureEngineer(df.copy(),
                    use_technical_indicator=True,
                    use_turbulence=False).preprocess_data()


# add covariance matrix as states
df=df.sort_values(['date','tic'],ignore_index=True)
df.index = df.date.factorize()[0]

cov_list = []
# look back is one year
lookback=252
for i in range(lookback,len(df.index.unique())):
  data_lookback = df.loc[i-lookback:i,:]
  price_lookback=data_lookback.pivot_table(index = 'date',columns = 'tic', values = 'close')
  return_lookback = price_lookback.pct_change().dropna()
  covs = return_lookback.cov().values 
  cov_list.append(covs)
  
df_cov = pd.DataFrame({'date':df.date.unique()[lookback:],'cov_list':cov_list})
df = df.merge(df_cov, on='date')
df = df.sort_values(['date','tic']).reset_index(drop=True)
df.head()
```

Comment: You'll need to provide the code of `FeatureEngineer.__init__`

Answer (score 0):

The function definition statement for [`FeatureEngineer.__init__` is](https://github.com/AI4Finance-LLC/FinRL-Library/blob/e0f5d807618e3e5029de92da4a875e81ec06454b/finrl/preprocessing/preprocessors.py):

```py
 def __init__(
        self,
        use_technical_indicator=True,
        tech_indicator_list=config.TECHNICAL_INDICATORS_LIST,
        use_turbulence=False,
        user_defined_feature=False,
    ):
```

As you can see there is no argument (other than self which you should not provide) before `use_technical_indicator`, so you should remove the df.copy() from before the `use_techincal_indicator` in your line 2.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the current [FeatureEngineer class](https://github.com/AI4Finance-LLC/FinRL/blob/master/finrl/preprocessing/preprocessors.py), you must to provide the `df.copy()` parameter to the `preprocess_data()` method.

So, your code have to look like:

```
# Perform Feature Engineering:
df = FeatureEngineer(use_technical_indicator=True,
                  tech_indicator_list = config.TECHNICAL_INDICATORS_LIST,
                  use_turbulence=True,
                  user_defined_feature = False).preprocess_data(df.copy())
```